# iOS 14 UISlider ignoring additional GestureRecognizer (PanGesture, LongTapGesture, TapGesture)

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uislider

I have a view controller in which a user can move around UIButton, UISlider, and a custom UIView based control by panning the control around the screen. This view controller is used to create custom layout of control by the user.  This is all done by adding PanGestureRecognizer to the UIControl to move the position of the control relative to user's finger location.

```
let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan))
panRecognizer.delegate = self;
myslider.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)

~~~~~~~~~~~~
//pan handler method

@objc func pan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: view)
        
        guard let gestureView = gestureRecognizer.view else {
            return
        }
        //Move the center to user's finger location
        gestureView.center = CGPoint(x: gestureView.center.x + translation.x, y: gestureView.center.y + translation.y);
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: view);

        if (gestureRecognizer.state == .ended) {
           //Save the new location inside data. Not relevant here.
        }
}
```

This worked fine in iOS 13 and below for all the control i mentioned above (with the UISlider being a bit glitchy but it still responded to the pan gesture and i don't need the value of the uislider anyway so it's safe to ignore). However testing the app in iOS 14 reveals that UISlider completely ignore the PanGesture (proven by adding breakpoint that never got called inside the pan gesture handling method).
I have looked at apple's documentation regarding UISlider and found no change at all related to gesture handling so this must be done deliberately in deeper lever. My question is: is there any way to "force" my custom gesture to be executed instead of UISlider's gesture without the need to create transparent button overlay (which i don't know will work or not) / creating dummy slider just for this ?

Additionally i also added UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer to the control. Which worked fine on other UIButton but completely ignored by the UISlider in iOS14 (in iOS 13 everything worked fine).

Thanks.

Comment: I tested on iOS 14 simulator. I just had to make the VC class conform to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. It works well, I can move the slider in the view. Where did you create panRecognizer ? In viewDidLoad ? Did you insert a print statement at the beginning of pan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) to check it is called ? Haven't you set constraints on the slider which prevents from moving ?

Comment: Tested as well with XCode 12ß4. Works perfectly.  So, I ask again: Where did you create panRecognizer ?

Comment: Okay.. so i just dig some more and i found the source of the problem. I created a new project, do the same as above, and it work as expected, like you said. The problem was with beginTracking method. This UISlider of Mine is subclassed into a custom class, with overriden beginTracking method that always return true. In iOS 13, this method does not "Override" the gestureRecognizer. However, in iOS 14, the behaviour changes, causing my problem.

Comment: Great you found the cause. But please, next time, describe properly the situation. You never said you subclassed UISlider, no one can guess it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. I found the answer myself after some more digging and getting cue from "claude31" about making a new clean project and testing from there.

The problem was with the overriden beginTracking function. This UISlider of mine is actually subclassed into a custom class and in there the beginTracking function is overriden, as per code below:

```
override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let percent = Float(touch.location(in: self).x / bounds.size.width)
    let delta = percent * (maximumValue - minimumValue)

    let newValue = minimumValue + delta
    self.setValue(newValue, animated: false)
    super.sendActions(for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    return true

}
```

This is to make the slider move immediately to the user finger location if the touch is inside the boundaries of the UISlider (without the need to first touch the thumbTrack and sliding it to the position the user wants).

In iOS 13 this function does not block the gestureRecognizer from getting recognized. However in iOS 14B4, overriding this function, with sendActions(for:) method inside it cause the added gestureRecognizer to be ignored completely, be it pan gesture, long press gesture, or even tap gesture.

For me, the solution is to simply add a state to check whether the pan gesture is required in this view controller or not. Because, luckily, i only need the added gestureRecognizer in view controller that does not require the beginTouch function to be customized and vice versa.

---

Edit:
Originally i wrote that the cause of the problem is due to always true return value, however, I just reread the documentation and the default return value for this function is also true. So i think the root causes of this problem is the sendActions(for:) method, causing the added gestureRecognizer to be ignored. My Answer above has been edited to reflect this.